# Boostrap+Rails white space under button group in table row

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a problem with my button group in one of table cells. 
It look like in the image I present below:

[image]

View file:

```
= render 'layouts/navbar'
= render 'layouts/sidebar'

div class = 'container-fluid'
  div class =  'col-sm-2'
  div class =  'col-sm-10'
    h1 Listing Copies
    table class = 'table table-hover'
      thead
        tr
          th Title
          th Author
          th Photo
          th Options

      tbody
        - @copies.each do |copy|
          tr class = 'warning'
            td = copy.book.title
            td = copy.book.author
            td = image_tag( copy.photo, class: 'preview')
            td class = 'btn-group'
              - if copy.returned?
                = link_to 'Rent', new_history_path(copy_id: copy.id), class: 'btn btn-primary'
              - else
                = link_to 'Rent', new_history_path(copy_id: copy.id), disabled: true, class: 'btn btn-danger'
              = link_to 'Show', copy, class: 'btn btn-default'
              = link_to 'Edit', edit_copy_path(copy), class: 'btn btn-default'
              = link_to 'Destroy', copy, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-default'
    = link_to 'New Copy', new_copy_path, class: 'btn btn-default'
```

And some css:

```
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
}
```

Any suggestions would really help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this - I shouldn't be doing `td class = 'btn-group'`. Instead of this:

```
td
  div class = 'btn-group'
```